# PHP: Why is True a Number but not Numeric?

Tags: php, boolean, isnumeric

So I'm trying to understand WHY this occurs:

```
<?php
$a = TRUE;          
$b = FALSE;

echo "a is ".$a."<br/>";
if (is_numeric($a)){
echo "a is numeric<br/>";
}
echo "b is ".$b."<br/>";
if (is_numeric($b)){
echo "b is numeric<br/>";
}   

?>
```

gives the following output

> a is 1
>
> b is

So A is considered to be 1 but not considered to be numeric.

The manual says that a string like "42" is considerd numeric.

Comment: I had to think about this one! The internal type, as recorded by PHP, will be Boolean, but it is cast to an integer when you echo it, or if you perform a maths operation on it.

Comment: Thanks, so it is recast if multiply by a boolean! oh....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not considered numeric. It is auto-converted to 1 when you `echo` it. This is called [type juggling](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php) and it means stuff like this is actually legal in PHP:

```
php > $a = true;
php > $b = $a + 5;
php > echo $b;
6

php > $c = "hello ".$a;
php > echo $c;
hello 1
```

You can use [`is_bool`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-bool.php) to find out it is actually boolean.

Comment: Thanks. So it isn-t a string "1" then, because the manual says that a string is considered to be numeric? Why dont they echo 0 for false?

Comment: It isn't a string. It's a boolean. It is auto-converted to a string `"1"` when echoing.

Comment: Answer chosen for citing type juggling in this context, with example. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

`true` is not numeric, but when it's converted to a string for concatenation, it is converted to `"1"`. Similarly, `false` is converted to the empty string `""`.

If you were to do:

```
$a_string = "$a";
```

Then `is_numeric($a_string)` would be true, because the value of `$a_string` would be `"1"`. Using a boolean in a context that requires a string converts the value to either `"1"` or `""`.

Comment: Thanks, the manual does say though that numeric strings are considerd numeric though.

Comment: That's true, but you don't have any numeric strings in your code.

Comment: If you did `is_numeric("$a")` that would be a numeric string.

Comment: Yeah, its just that I was wondering if the TRUE is "1", when does it become "1" because a variable equal to the echoed TRUE would be numeric, no?

Answer (score 2):

The value false is not a constant for the number 0, it is a boolean value that indicates false.  The value true is also not a constant for 1, it is a special boolean value that indicates true.  It just happens to cast to integer 1 when you print it or use it in an expression, but it's not the same as a constant for the integer value 1 and you shouldn't use it as one. But there may be times when it might be helpful to see the value of the Boolean as a 1 or 0. Here's how to do it.

```
<?php 
 $var1 = TRUE; 
 $var2 = FALSE; 

  echo $var1; // Will display the number 1 

  echo $var2; //Will display nothing 

  /* To get it to display the number 0 for 
  a false value you have to typecast it: */ 

  echo (int)$var2; //This will display the number 0 for false. 

 var_dump($var1); //bool(true)

 var_dump($var2); //bool(false) 

 ?>
```

References:

[Bool](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php)

[var_dump](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php)

Comment: Thnaks, although why we are allowed to see TRUE directly makes me wonder if it has some numeric aspect...

Comment: Being a dynamic language everything should be castable to anything depending on context.

Comment: @Gamemorize When you do a `var_dump($var1);` the output is `bool(true)`

Answer (score 1):

`$a` is not considered 1. It's *represented* as the string "1" when echoed.

Comment: Thanks, so it is never a string though?

Comment: @Gamemorize No. You need to understand that PHP hwill often convert values from one type to another as needed by context. But the original types are still distinct.